# python reduce error?

Tags: python, lambda, arguments, reduce

The following is my python code:

```
>>> item = 1
>>> a = []
>>> a.append((1,2,3))
>>> a.append((7,2,4))
>>> sums=reduce(lambda x:abs(item-x[1]),a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>>
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please note that `sum` is a built-in function in python, and so it is recommended that you use a different name, like I did in my answer.

Comment: I have change the sum to sums, and the same error occures.

Comment: Yes, of course. The answers below explain what the real problem is. I just said it is a better practice to now shadow the `sum` function :)

Comment: Furthermore, I think you can see from the answers that it is not clear what it is that you're trying to do. Can you add a description of what that code is supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 8):

Your lambda takes only one argument, but `reduce` requires a function that takes two arguments. Make your lambda take two arguments.

Since you didn't say what you want this code to do, I'll just guess:

```
the_sum=reduce(lambda x,y:abs(y[1]-x[1]),a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem itself is a bit unclear. Anyway, i have taken just assumption--

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append((1,2,3))
>>> a.append((7,2,4))
>>> a
[(1, 2, 3), (7, 2, 4)] # list of tuples
```

I am assuming that you might be interested in getting the sum of all the elements in the list. If that is the problem then that could be solved in 2 steps

1) The first step should be to flatten the list.

2) And then add all the elements of the list.

```
>>> new_list = [y for x in a for y in x] # List comprehension used to flatten the list
[1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 4] 
>>> sum(new_list)
19
```

One liner

```
>>> sum([y for x in a for y in x])
19
```

**Another assumption, if your problem is to minus every element of tuple by item in the list then use this:**

```
>>> [tuple(map(lambda y: abs(item - y), x)) for x in a]
[(0, 1, 2), (6, 1, 3)] # map function always returns a list so i have used tuple function to convert it into tuple.
```

If the problem is something else then please elaborate.

PS: Python List comprehension is far better and efficient than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` expects the function it is given to accept 2 arguments. For every item in the iterable it will pass the function the current item, and the previous return value from the function. So, getting the sum of a list is `reduce(lambda: x,y: x+y, l, 0)`

If I understand correctly, to get the behavior you were trying to get, change the code to:

```
a_sum = reduce(lambda x,y: x + abs(item-y[1]), a, 0)
```

But I might be mistaken as to what you were trying to get. 
Further information is in the `reduce` function's docstring.